# How to used a previously generated tuple to generate a new tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, physics

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to generate a new tuple with a previously generated tuple. What I have so far is just generating an empty tuple

```
import math as m
grav = 9.807 #[m/s**2] gravity http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?gn value obtained from NIST
H = 1.100 #[m] Height of the posts/supports
rho = 2.000 #[kg/m] density of the chain
DIS = 0.980 # distance of supports from x = 0
SEG = 10000. #number of divisions
SEGL = 2*DIS/SEG # size of segments
aa = 0.6 #[m]

#xtuple
n=0
xterms = []
xterm = -DIS
while n<=SEG:
    xterms.append(xterm)
    n+=1
    xterm = -DIS + n*SEGL
#ytuple
yterms = []
yterm = H
while n<= SEG:
    yterms.append(yterm)
    n+=1
    yterm = H + aa*m.cosh(xterms[n]/aa) -aa*m.cosh(DIS/aa)
print yterms
```

What I eventually have to do is solve for the length with `sqrt((xi - x(i-1))^2 + (yi - y(i-1))^2)`. Then angles, net force and `aa` will have to vary from .6 to 3.9.

I can't use fancy functions as this is an intro course. I have to use such things as `(xterms[n] -xterms[n-1])**2`

Comment: So this is a homework assignment, right? Please show significant effort by explicitly stating your question and what you have tried, as well as what errors your are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, but I managed to figure out my silly mistake. This is the proper way to do it. I wrote out the process, by hand and it allowed me to come to this solution.

```
k=0
yterms = []
while k<=SEG:
    yterm = H + aa*m.cosh(xterms[k]/aa) -aa*m.cosh(DIS/aa)
    yterms.append(yterm)
    k+=1
print yterms
```

Sorry to waste your time

Comment: In the future, you can use a for loop and [range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) or [xrange](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) to iterate through the different values of k. You won't need to worry about your code failing due to the placement of the increment term, and your variable will be unique to each loop so it won't need to be reset.

Answer (score 1):

Your `yterms` is empty because `n` is still 10001 from the first loop.

Comment: but if I resent n=0 I get "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: that's because N in the second while loop becomes larger than the length of "xterms". you're trying to say xterms[n] where n is outside of the range of indices.

Comment: That's right and you skip over the `x[0]` element by accessing `xterms[1]` first.

Comment: i figured it out, i'll post my solution in 7.5 hours

Answer (score 0):

The second while loop isn't executed because n is already greater than SEG.

Comment: I figured out my problem, i'll post my solution in 7.5 hours